# DX11 How to guarantee rendering order using Deferred Context?

Tags: directx11

What techniques are used to guarantee rendering order (back to front) when you have more than one deferred context?

My original idea was to manually remap the Command Lists, but it seems like this is not possible.

Do games just render all Alpha objects using the immediate context (to guarantee order)?

Thanks!

Comment: A deferred context is not actually drawn until you execute it on the immediate context, so the order you submit them is going to control draw order.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn But if you have lets say 2 work threads, and you are pumping assets to each one from back to front order, then each thread will zig-zag the actual order. When it comes time to execute the command list from thread 1, and then thread 2, it wont actually be in order, right?

Comment: You still have the sort merge problem of course. That said, you usually want to render opaque geometry front-to-back (to maximum the efficiency of z-culling), and then render transparent geometry back-to-front (to get correctly blended results) so you are better off doing opaque & transparent in different passes anyhow.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Okay!  As I thought, there is a underlining issue if you have more than 1 worker thread, even with transparent rendering, it will not 100% be in order since there are multiple worker threads.  Is this technical term called "Merge Problem" and is there any solutions to it?  Or do you just live with the out of order rendering that will happen.

Comment: To get 'correct' ordering, you always need to have a distinct pass for opaque vs. transparent objects. That or each worker thread produces two deferred contexts: One for opaque and one for transparent.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn I understand to render each of them separate alpha objects are from back to front.  Lets assume a workflow of 1 single que system and each worker thread takes from the top of the que.  Do systems like this just live with the fact that one thread might be faster than another, which means ordering will be slightly off?  If you render object B before object A, does it really matter in the long run?  Since you have to render from back to front for alpha objects, this would also create some artifacts ... Just wanted some information on these matters in design.

Comment: You have to bucket opaque VS. transparent in some fashion to get correct order. Either you work in parallel or in two passes, but in the end you need to make sure you submit all the deferred contexts for opaque *before* you submit the ones for transparent for drawing.